# How to create table from user input?

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I've been searching for hours, and I can't seem to find the answer that I've been looking for. I want to create a table(**a subject table**) based on user input (User will only input table name) and inside that table, the user can add information (like **students enrolled in that particular subject**. Is this possible in android? I'm using eclipse. I'm really a *newbie* in android programming. Can you please give me some tips what to search or what should I try doing to achieve this. Please help I'm just asking for advice/tips/tutorials that might help me. Thanks in advance. Sorry for my bad English.
[image: OUTPUT]

NOTE: The main problem here is I don't know how to create table from user input. Please I need advice/tips.

Comment: Do you know how to create tables in SQLite?

Comment: Yes. Pardon me for being a total newbie.

Comment: Then I don't see where do you have problems. You will take the user input text(from the `EditText` or whatever input method you have in mind), check the input(not all users are nice guys) and then create the table in sqlite with a `execSQL()` call.

Comment: the problem is i don't know how can I check the input to create the table. :( how can I equal user input to table name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm still not sure where do you have problems, but I'm posting this because it's too big for a comment. In your current setup, let's assume that you have an `EditText` where the user will enter the new subject(like `math` for example). To make the new table you'll need two operations: to insert the math text in the subject table and then actually create the new math table. You'll need to do this in a transaction to make sure this operations either succeed or fail as one( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29 ). First, to insert the math text in the subject table you'll use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29 . Then to create the new math table you'll do:

```
// get the text entered by the user, also trim it for extra spaces
String newTableName = editTextInput.getText().trim(); 
// the entered name should consist only of characters
newTableName = newTableName.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
// create the new table
sqliteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + newTableName);
```

The way you setup the database is far from ideal. You should avoid creating tables for each of the subject table entries(and for the students as well, I'm assuming a student will be engaged in more than one course), instead you should create a subject table, a students tables(each with a unique id) and one table that joins the two of them(also look at sqlite foreign keys).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the idea! Also thanks for your advise about my database setup. I will to research more about that.